# Insert data from 2 table where not exists

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I wanted to insert data from table temporary to table original

The structure is same but have 3 key 
like this

```
table original 
{NIP_SPV  nvarchar (10),
NIP_SUB nvarchar (10),
TransActionDate date,
...
}
```

I wanted to insert data where data does not already exist

my code looks like this

```
IF NOT EXISTS ( 
   SELECT * FROM table_original a Inner Join table_temp b  
   on a.transactiondate = b.transactiondate and a.nip_spv = b.nip_spv 
   and a.nip_sub = b.nip_sub )  
      Begin 
        INSERT INTO T_EmployeeGroup 
        select nip_spv,nip_sub,spv_usertype,sub_usertype,appr_year  
        from table_temp
      END
 Else 
    Begin
      Update  A
      A.column_n =B.column_n
      from table_original A
      Inner JOIN table_temp B 
      on  a.transactiondate = b.transactiondate and a.nip_spv = b.nip_spv 
      and a.nip_sub = b.nip_sub
    end
```

The case is

```
when i insert data for the second time is failed
 first case i insert 10 data
 second case i insert 20 data(10 old data from first case)
```

I failed insert 10 data from new data.

What did I miss?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an `OUTER JOIN` for this and filter on null values:

```
INSERT INTO table_original 
SELECT b.* FROM table_temp b
RIGHT JOIN table_original a ON a.transactiondate = b.transactiondate
                          AND a.nip_spv = b.nip_spv 
                          AND a.nip_sub = b.nip_sub
WHERE b.transactiondate IS NULL
  AND b.nip_spv IS NULL
  AND b.nip_sub IS NULL
```